# How can I get the creation time of a Data Lake Database or Data Lake Table

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am writing a powershell script to clean up old databases or tables, but found the object returned from Get-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogItem doesn't have creation time.

Comment: Are you looking for a PowerShell only solution?  If no, you could use U-SQL to query the [usql.databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt826844.aspx) catalog view.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes I am looking for a powershell solution, but good to know they have the ability in USQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$DataLakeAnalyticsAccount = "yourAccountNameHere";
$outputFile = "ReferenceGuide/CatalogViews/CreateDate.txt";  
$jobName = "GetCreateDate";

# U-SQL query
[string]$body = 
"@query = 
SELECT ""Database"" AS Object, name, create_date FROM usql.databases
UNION ALL
SELECT type_desc, ""master."" + name AS Table, create_date FROM     master.usql.objects WHERE type == ""U""
UNION ALL
SELECT type_desc, ""TestReferenceDB."" + name AS Table, create_date FROM TestReferenceDB.usql.objects WHERE type == ""U"";
";

# OUTPUT statement
[string]$output = 
"OUTPUT @query 
TO ""$outputFile""
ORDER BY Object
USING Outputters.Tsv();";

# bring it all together
$script = $body +  $output;

#Execute job``
$jobInfo = Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob -Account $DataLakeAnalyticsAccount -Name $jobName  -Script $script -DegreeOfParallelism 1

#check job progress
Get-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob -Account $DataLakeAnalyticsAccount -JobId     $jobInfo.JobId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
```